# using Redis in node.js for receive socket.io ack

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

I use this code on the server to send an emit event and listen for "ack" from the client. However, if the client disconnects or never gets the emit event, I want to continuously send that event until client sends "ack".

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    redis.setConnectionId(socket.decoded_token.connection_prefix + socket.decoded_token.id, socket.id);


    socket.on('connectionInterrupt', async function () {
        if(socket.decoded_token.connection_prefix == riderPrefix) {
            //messages that not yet received by client
            const messages = await redis.getAllSocketEventsNotConsumed(riderPrefixMessageQueue + socket.decoded_token.id);
            //user socketId
            const riderConnectionId = await redis.getConnectionId(riderPrefix + socket.decoded_token.id);


            if(messages) {// so some message not received by user

                if(messages['driverAccepted'] != null) {//this event not received by client


                    let travel = await mysql.travel.getById(messages['driverAccepted']);

                    if(travel.status != mysql.travel.TRAVEL_ERROR_DRIVER_CANCELED) {

                        const driver = await mysql.driver.getDriverInfo(travel.fk_driver);

                        console.log('send msg again to socketId:' + riderConnectionId);

                        //send faild event again and if this time received by client remove from redis
                        io.sockets.connected[riderConnectionId].emit('driverAccepted', driver, async function() {
                            console.log('rider ack');
                            await redis.removeSocketEmitEvent(riderPrefixMessageQueue+travel.fk_rider, 'driverAccepted');
                        });
                    }

                }

            }
        }


    });

});
```

Comment: It's possible. Have you tried doing any integration so far with Redis? Gotta ask that age old stack overflow question of "what have you tried?"

Comment: @MattFletcher i wrote some code but at the end driver variable, not send to client and it will loop and loop again, i dont know why